# terraform: metadata_startup_script like mechanism for azure

Tags: linux, azure, terraform, initialization

I'm following a [blog to Deploy a Debian Linux VM Instance in GCP using Terraform](https://gmusumeci.medium.com/how-to-deploy-a-debian-linux-vm-instance-in-gcp-using-terraform-65d872832218), in which it uses `metadata_startup_script` Bootstrapping Script to Install/config packages.

I'm following in Azure instead of GCP, and got:

`An argument named "metadata_startup_script" is not expected here.`

Is `metadata_startup_script` **GCP** provider speicific? What's the corresponding mechanism in the terraform **Azure** provider ? For e.g. to do the following,

```bash
sudo apt-get update; 
sudo apt-get install -y apache2;
sudo systemctl start apache2;
sudo systemctl enable apache2;
```

to bootstrap the provided Linux VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute `metadata_startup_script` doesn't exist on Azure VMs, its similar is `user_data`[1].

References:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine#user_data

Comment: Thanks, would you elaborate a bit more on how to make use of the `user_data` to achieve the same bootstrap code I provided in OP please?

Comment: You can use the Terraform cloud-init provider https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/cloudinit/latest/docs/data-sources/cloudinit_config or you can directly use the `file` function to read your script file with the `base64encode` function and pass the result to the `user_data` attribute.